# Border Bottom left to right when Div Hover using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do **blue border animation at the bottom** of box-like below image.

[image]

*But in my code, it displayed in the box.*
**My code is**

```css
.b-shadow:hover {
                box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);border:1px solid #edeaea; border-radius:5px;
            }
              .b-shadow:hover:after {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .b-top > div:after {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 0;
                height: 2px;
                background: #000;
                transition: width .3s;
            }

                .b-shadow {
                    border: 1px solid transparent
                }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 b-top" style="padding:50px 30px;">
        <div class="col-md-6  b-shadow" style="
            padding:20px">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
            <div style="color:#000;">
                <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
                <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 b-shadow" style="padding:20px;">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
            <div style="color:#000;">
                <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
                <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need a border at the bottom of the div like below image
[image: Correct snippet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `position: relative` for `b-shadow` class elements and `position: absolute` for pseudoelemen with `bottom` property ajust

Result

```css
.b-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: 1px solid #edeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.b-shadow:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.b-top>div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  transition: width .3s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.b-shadow {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 b-top" style="padding:50px 30px;">
  <div class="col-md-6  b-shadow" style="
            padding:20px">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
    <div style="color:#000;">
      <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
      <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 b-shadow" style="padding:20px;">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
    <div style="color:#000;">
      <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
      <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pritesh, if the answer helped, you can mark it with a solution

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```css
.b-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: 1px solid #edeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative; /* provide positioning context for :after */
}

.b-shadow:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.b-top>div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  transition: width .3s;

  /* position at the bottom of the container */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.b-shadow {
  border: 1px solid transparent
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 b-top" style="padding:50px 30px;">
  <div class="col-md-6  b-shadow" style="
            padding:20px">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
    <div style="color:#000;">
      <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
      <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 b-shadow" style="padding:20px;">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
    <div style="color:#000;">
      <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
      <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.b-shadow:hover {
                box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);border:1px solid #edeaea; border-radius:5px;
            }
              .b-shadow:hover:after {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .b-top > div:after {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 0;
                height: 2px;
                background: #000;
                transition: width .3s;
            }

                .b-shadow {
                    border: 1px solid transparent
                }


<div class="col-md-12 b-top" style="padding:50px 30px;">
 <div class="b-shadow">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="
            padding:20px">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
            <div style="color:#000;">
                <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
                <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="b-shadow">
        <div class="col-md-6 " style="padding:20px;">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
            <div style="color:#000;">
                <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
                <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
          </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Blue border** like your first image.
try this

```css
.b-shadow:hover {
                box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);border:1px solid #edeaea; border-radius:5px;
            }
              .b-shadow:hover:after {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .b-top > div:after {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 0;
                height: 2px;
                background:#0000FF;
                transition: width .3s;
            }

                .b-shadow {
                    border: 1px solid transparent
                }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 b-top" style="padding:50px 30px;">
        <div class="col-md-6  b-shadow" style="
            padding:20px">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
            <div style="color:#000;">
                <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
                <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 b-shadow" style="padding:20px;">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-question-mark-in-a-speech-bubble-icon-720160648.jpg" width="50px" />
            <div style="color:#000;">
                <h3 style="font-weight:600;">Learning Center</h3>
                <p>Use the Learning Center&nbsp;to find an answer on your own.&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Border at the bottom